# Return belonging name with ID form Laravel, check for the type?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

sorry for the title of this question but I am not sure how to ask it...

I am working on a project where I have two Models Trains and Cars, to this model I have a belonging Route.

I want to make a query and check if the `routeable_type` is `App\Car` than with the selected `routeable_id` to get the data from the Car. And if the `routeable_type` is Train then with the ID to get the data from the Tran.

So my models go like this:

Train:

```
class Train extends Model
{
  public function routes()
  {
      return $this->morphMany('App\Route', 'routeable');
  }

}
```

Car:

```
class Car extends Model
{
  public function routes()
  {
      return $this->morphMany('App\Route', 'routeable');
  }

}
```

Route:

```
class Route extends Model
{
  public function routeable()
  {
      return $this->morphTo();
  }
}
```

And the query I have at the moment is:

```
$data = Route::leftjoin('cars', 'cars.id', '=', 'routes.routeable_id')
    ->leftjoin('trains', 'trains.id', '=', 'routes.routeable_id')
    ->select('routes.id', 'cars.model AS carmodel', 'trains.model AS trainmodel', 'routeable_type', 'routes.created_at');
```

With this query if I have the same ID in cars and trains I get the data from both and all messes up. How do I check if routeable_type is Car ... do this, if routeable_type is Train .. do that?

Will something like this be possible in a 1 single query:

```
$data = Route::select('routes.id', 'routeable_type', 'routes.created_at');

if(routeable_type == 'Car'){
  $data = $data->leftjoin('cars', 'cars.id', '=', 'routes.routeable_id')->select('routes.id', 'cars.model AS carmodel', 'routeable_type', 'routes.created_at');
}else{
  $data = $data->leftjoin('trains', 'trains.id', '=', 'routes.routeable_id')->select('routes.id', 'trains.model AS trainmodel', 'routeable_type', 'routes.created_at');
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the full code? Especially where you are writing the query. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Mozammil I want to use it with `Datatables` and display all the data in a table.

Comment: Why are you just eager loading the relationship?

Comment: @RossWilson I want to show a table of all routes and in this table I want to show the model of the vehicle that is on the route. And this is the only way I kinda know how to do it.

Comment: Please can you add your entire controller method to your question? Also, are you using Yajra datables and if so what version?

Comment: Are you using Yajra datables by the way i.e. the laravel specific one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
DB::table('routes')
    ->leftJoin('cars', function ($join) {
        $join->on('cars.id', '=', 'routes.routeable_id')
            ->where('routes.routeable_type', 'App\Car');
    })
    ->leftJoin('trains', function ($join) {
        $join->on('trains.id', '=', 'routes.routeable_id')
            ->where('routes.routeable_type', 'App\Train');
    })
    ->select('routes.id', 'cars.model AS car_model', 'trains.model AS train_model', 'routes.routeable_type', 'routes.created_at');
    ->get();
```

Comment: This is almost the perfect solution, the only thing left is when I try to select the "model" of the results in one column I am getting `1052 Column "model" in field list is ambiguous"`

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to follow the morphedByMany design.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

This was also a neat visual for the different relation types.

https://hackernoon.com/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209

I was faced with a similar issue though I failed to follow the correct design initially and was forced to query the many possible relations then wrote custom logic after to collect the relation types and ids then do another query and assign them back through iteration. It was ugly but worked... very similar to how Eloquent does things normally.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have enough repo, so i can't comment. that's why i am putting as an answer.

You should use 2 different queries, for each model.

This will be better, code wise as well as performance wise. also if both models have similar fields you should merge them to 1 table and add a 'type' column.
and put non-similar fields in a 'meta' column.
( in my opinion )